# Why is my condition expression giving a syntax error?

Tags: python

```py
def singleNumber(nums):
    for num in set(nums):
         return num if nums.count(num) != 2 #error occurs here

print(singleNumber([1,1,4,5,5]))
```

This follows the usual python condition expression format. I don't understand why it's giving me a syntax error here.

The purpose of this function is to find number that doesn't occur twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to actually execute a `return`, you must return *something* no matter what.

So you could *try*:

```
return num if nums.count(num) != 2 else None
```

However, that's not going to work in this case since it will return on the *first* check rather checking *all* the elements for what you want.

In other words, let's say the first element checked is the first `1` in `[1,1,4,5,5]`. It will work out that there are two copies of that value in the array and then return `None`, skipping the rest of the elements.

I'd probably rewrite it as:

```
if nums.count(num) != 2: return num
```

which basically does what you need in that, if you *don't* explicitly return something (i.e., all of the values occur twice), the caller gets `None` implicitly when the function exits.

If you're the type that *dislikes* implicit things, you can explicitly add `return None` at the end of the function, though it's not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot to write what the result should be if the condition is false.

```
return num if nums.count(num) != 2 else ...what?
```

And if you didn't want that then you should write a normal `if` statement instead.

Comment: What if I don't want it to return anything?

Comment: return num if nums.count(num) != 2 else None

Comment: To be fair, the last line of this answer wasn't there in the first go, so it's possible JADP was looking at the original version.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a ternary conditional operator both if and else part are mandatory.

```
return num if nums.count(num) != 2 else <missing???>
```